# Key-bindings for public static void main() and System.out.println() in Sublime Text 2

Tags: java, sublimetext2

I have recently gone from coding java in emacs to doing it in sublime text 2. I would like to know how to create key bindings such that if I type sop I'll get System.out.println() and if I type psvm I'll get public static void main. I'm using Sublime Text 2 for Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html).

`Tools/New Snippet...`:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
System.out.println()
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>sop</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.java</scope>
</snippet>
```

Save this file with `.sublime-snippet` extension, in `Packages/User`.

This way, in Java source files, when you type `sop`, followed by <kbd>tab</kbd>, you'll get what you need.

You can do the same for `psvm`.

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can use snippets, but for what you're asking, you can just type:

**pl[tab]** for

```
System.out.println();
```

and **main[tab]** for

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```